# How to disable ssh non-interactive commands from the server side?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, openssh

Currently I have a server with openssh7.1 installed, which supports non-interactive commands like : ssh user@server ls. Is there a way to disable such type of command on the server side?

Answer (score 3):

There is `ForceCommand` keyword in `sshd_config`:

> `ForceCommand`
> Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand, ignoring any command supplied by the client and `~/.ssh/rc` if present. The command is invoked by using the user's login shell with the `-c` option. This applies to shell, command, or subsystem execution. It is most useful inside a Match block. The command originally supplied by the client is available in the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable. […]

<sup>([source](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ForceCommand))</sup>

If you use it like this:

```
ForceCommand    exec /bin/sh -i
```

then you will force interactive `sh`. There are at least two problems with this simple approach:

1. I haven't found any simple way to force tty allocation by configuring the server. A client can choose, the server may allow or refuse (with [`PermitTTY`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PermitTTY)). When forcing interactive `sh`, supposedly it would be good to force tty allocation. I may have missed something; it doesn't matter because on the other hand…
2. A client trying to run a non-interactive command does not expect interactive shell instead. A better way to disable such command is to make it fail. Probably this is what you want.

Therefore:

```
ForceCommand    if [ "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ]; then echo "this server rejects non-interactive ssh usage" >&2; exit 1; else exec "$SHELL" -i; fi
```

Notes:

- `ForceCommand` uses the user's login shell with the `-c` option. Our command uses portable syntax, it should work in many shells. If the user can choose something non-standard as his or her login shell then the command may misbehave. Consider putting the command in a script (with proper shebang) and executing the script instead (`ForceCommand /path/to/the_script`).
- `$SHELL` will most likely work as expected, still I think the variable is not strictly required by POSIX. You may prefer `${SHELL:-/bin/sh}` or something similar instead.